# Array initiliazation using new and values but no explicit number of elements

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, new-operator

In many C-family languages it is possible to initialize an array with the number of elements implicit from the list of initial elements. E.g. in Java:

```java
int[] ints = new int[] {0, 1, 2, ...}
```

On page 597 of 'Programming: Principles and Practice using C++', Stroustrup writes that it is possible to use a similar syntax in C++:

```cpp
double* p5 = new double[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

However, when trying to compile this using GCC or Clang, I get errors because an expression is expected in the brackets:

```
$ g++ main.cpp
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:17:26: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
  double* p5 = new double[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
                          ^
main.cpp:17:41: error: too many initializers for 'double [1]'
  double* p5 = new double[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
                                         ^
```

And with Clang:

```
 $ clang++ main.cpp
 main.cpp:17:26: error: expected expression
         double* p5 = new double[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
                                 ^
 main.cpp:17:19: error: excess elements in scalar initializer
         double* p5 = new double[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
                          ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 2 errors generated.
```

Is the book wrong on this? I've seen at least one SO user recommending this to someone with an unrelated problem (that code didn't compile for me either).

Comment: How about `double p5[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};`? `double* p5 = new double[5] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};` seems to work. Probably a typo in the book.

Comment: `std::vector<double> p5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};` is the C++ way to do this.

Comment: Or `std::array<double, 5> p5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};` if the array is of fixed size.

Comment: @NathanOliver: a `std::vector` and a raw array are not the same thing at all. I agree that many users try to use raw arrays when they should use `std::vector` or `std::array`, but raw arrays do have legitimate use cases.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The OP isn't using a raw array.  They want to use `new[]`, which means they should use a vector, or some other RAII type to handle the subsequent `delete[]`.  I've no problem with `double p5[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};`.  Although I could be misinterpreting it as they start with a Java example where you have to use `new` instead of like what we can do in C++

Comment: @NathanOliver: I assume that OP wants a dynamically allocated array. I cannot really guess whether it is a an appropriate use case (AFAIK the only real world one is the explicit implementation of a container).

Comment: @NathanOliver I know that you shouldn't normally use arrays directly. This particular chapter in the book discusses the implementation of containers (vectors in particular).

Answer (score -1):

It seems a mistake in the book.
Arrays in C++ are not objects like Java, it is a block in memory that has a pointer pointing at the first element, so the syntax `new double[] {}` is not reasonable.

use:

```
double * d = {1,2,3,4};
```

Comment: An array is slightly more than a block of memory. It is an aggregate and the compiler knows the type of its elements and their number. What is true is that arrays are not first class objects in C++

Comment: The number of elements are stored in a slot before the array memory block, the operator `new` of arrays allocate memory and store the number of elements in this slot.

Comment: This doesn't compile as `{1,2,3,4}` isn't an actual thing.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1589d2ab5ecf666

Comment: @ammcom: what you describe is only an implementation detail. Not all implementations are required to do that.

Answer (score -1):

C++ allows to omit the size of an array when **in a array declaration**, the size can be deduced from an initializer, for example in:

```
double d[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };   // ok 5 elements
char std[] = "foo";               // ok 4 elements with the terminating null
```

But `double* p5 = new double[5];` is not a array declaration. It declares a raw pointer that is initialized to point to a dynamically allocated array.

Both declarations do have very close semantics, because for example both allow for partial initialization (`double* p5 = new double[5]{0, 1, 2};`). But the syntax you propose is not defined in the standard and is not accepted by current versions of Clang or gcc.

It would be easy to extend the language to accept it but IMHO it is unlikely to happen:

- arrays are not first class elements of the language, and programmers are advised to use containers instead
- raw pointers are no longer first class elements, and programmers are advised to use references or smart pointers instead